# Cannot be resolved or is not a field error?

Tags: java, android

When I created my new project, I set my minimium SDK version API to 14 (4.0 IceCreamSandwich). The Target API 19(4.4 KitKat). Compile API 19(4.4 KitKat).

In starting my project this way I'm getting the error "R cannot be resolved to variable". So I went ahead and fixed the issue by regenerating my R.java and BuildConfig.java files by going to Project->clean. My R.java and BuildConfig.java is now generated. My error "R cannot be resolved to variable" is now gone.

Here's my problem. When I add a new object, button, textview etc.. and try and set the contentview or findviewbyid to the object that I created in my XML file it's not finding it, I'm getting the error "splash cannot be resolved or is not a field"?

In order to find the item, I have to edit my R.java file (which is something I know I shouldn't do). After I do this and run the project on the emulator I'm getting an error

So here's my question, how do I get my id's to show up in the R.java file without having to manually edit it? How do I get rid of the "splash cannot be resolved or is not a field" error? without messing around with my R.java file?

Thanks

Comment: Double check that you have Build Automatically option enabled under Build menu.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks